# C# regular expression to separate when match one contains match two

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text that will contain strings surrounded by `#[ ]`. I need to match these strings and find out the string inside.

My example text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor #[This is my first string.] sit amet, consectetur elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt #[This is my second string?] ut et dolore magna.
```

With this text I would like to have two matches:

```
#[This is my first string.]
#[This is my second string?]
```

Now I have written my regular expression:

```
\#\[([\w\s\W]*)\]
```

I added `\W` because I would like to include dots, question marks and other characters that is not a letter. This causes me a problem because now `#`, `[` and `]` is included which results in my text to have only one match:

```
#[This is my first string.] sit amet, consectetur elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt #[This is my second string?]
```

Of course it matches on the first occurrence of `#[` and the last occurrence of `]`.
How to solve this? I can accept to not include `#`, `[` and `]` in my strings but all other none-letter character should be included if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the `\W`, it's the `*`. The `*` is greedy and will match the longest string possible. So it matches the first `[` with the last `]` and takes everything in between.

Try this:

```
\#\[([\w\s\W]*?)\]
```

In fact, you should be able to simplify it to just:

```
\#\[(.*?)\]
```

The `?` after a qualifier (`*` or `+`) will force *minimal* matches. I.e. non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `\W` also matches `]`

The easy way to fix this is: after `[` match as many non `]` characters as possible:

```
(#\[[^\]]*\])
```

This should do the trick nicely.